# Laravel Modular Request to a different Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a github project named mnabialek/laravel-modular. The package works fine but I cant pass requests to a different controller in diffrent module. How can I do that.

TestModule Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\TestModule\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Modules\TestModule\Http\Requests\TestModuleRequest;
use App\Modules\Admin\Http\Requests\AdminRequest;
use App\Modules\TestModule\Repositories\TestModuleRepository;
use App\Modules\TestModule\Services\TestModuleService;

class TestModuleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var TestModuleRepository
     */
    protected $repo;

    /**
     * @var TestModuleService
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * TestModuleController constructor.
     *
     * @param TestModuleRepository $repo
     * @param TestModuleService $service
     */
    public function __construct(TestModuleRepository $repo, TestModuleService $service)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        //echo "Here you are";
        //$data["data"] = "Here you are";

        //return view("welcome")->with($data);
        $working = "Its Working";
        $message = App::make("App\\Modules\\Admin\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController")->create($working);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

}
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Admin\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Modules\Admin\Http\Requests\AdminRequest;
use App\Modules\Admin\Repositories\AdminRepository;
use App\Modules\Admin\Services\AdminService;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var AdminRepository
     */
    protected $repo;

    /**
     * @var AdminService
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * AdminController constructor.
     *
     * @param AdminRepository $repo
     * @param AdminService $service
     */
    public function __construct(AdminRepository $repo, AdminService $service)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create($working)
    {

        die(print_r($working));
        //
    }


}
```

Here is the error I am getting.

> Class 'App\Modules\TestModule\Http\Controllers\App' not found

Comment: Where is the class `App` being defined?

Comment: Check if class App exists

Comment: try importing manually `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;`

Comment: Use the `app()` helper instead of `App` i.e. `app()->make(...)` or you can use `\App` to reference the root scope alias of the `Application` facade (which I'm guessing is what you want to use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$message = Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::make("App\\Modules\\Admin\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController")->create($working);
```

As `App` does not exist in the current namespace, you have to call it from where it is defined.